# Moving from one subversion repository to multiple repostories

Tags: svn

Running on Windows I have a repository for a project, I would now like to put a completely unrelated project under source control within its own repository. I've read the various debates about using one repository per project or having all projects in one repository and for me I definitently prefer the one reposistory per project option but Im unsure how to do it.

My setup is very simple, Im the only user and the repository is on the same machine as it is checked out to, and I use svnserve from CollabNet

My repository is top level so my checkout code points to svn://localhost and my repository looks like this

C:\Repository
C:\Repository\conf
C:\Repository\db
C:\Repository\hooks
c:\Repository\logs

How do I get svnserve to serve multiple repostories ?

Comment: svnserve's `-r` option takes a directory *containing* repositories. This seems to be `C:\` in your case, which is quite puzzling. How do you currently start svnserve? I.e. what command line and configuration files do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best documentation for svnserve is not the SVN documentation, IMO, but the TortoiseSVN one. Read http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html.

You'll have to create another repository next to the first one and set the root directory to the parent directory of the two repositories.

You'll also have to relocate your existing working copies.

Comment: Thanks understood in principle, but go into services panel and it doesnt seem to let m,e edit services just stop or start them ?

Comment: Remove the service, and recreate it with the appropriate options. The syntax is described in the linked documentation.

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the --root flag a directory where all your repositories are located at.

You can read about it here: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html